# Vue vuex state watch is not working on first load

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have below code to get new ID using watch. Its working fine. However, I need the function to get the ID on first load as well, which is not working. Is there anything I am missing in my code?

```
watch: {
    id: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(newV, oldV) {
        this.id = newV;
      },
    },

  },
   mounted () {
    store.watch(store.getters.getId, id => {
      this.id = id;
    });
  },
  created() {
    this.userID();  
  },
  methods: {
      userID () {
         console.log('this.id);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just add `mounted()` property.

Comment: @mare96 I did, still didnt manage to get the value in methods

Comment: Can you provide more code?

Comment: How is vuex involved?

Comment: @mare96 Updated my question

Comment: All your watcher is doing is watching the `id` property on the current component and setting its value to equal the value it already has... What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can just do this:

```
data() {
  return {id: null}
}
watch: {
    '$store.getters.getId': {
      immediate: true,
      handler: function(newV) {
        this.id = newV
      },
    },
  }
```

Using a computed property is better, as your component does not 'own the id'.

```
computed: {
    id() {
      return this.$store.getters.getId
    },
  },
```

Comment: when I print this.id in methods, it prints undefined.

Comment: I forgot '()' in computed.  Try that one now.  Don't define id in data either.

Comment: What is the directed path to your state property? (not using getters).  Use that to test.  this.$store.state.id, etc.  Also, if async, I might not be set when your method runs.

Comment: state: {
        id: null,
    },

Comment: Where to you set $store.state.id?